# Client Server message encryption

Tags: java, encryption, ionic2

I am using an Ionic 2 client and a Java Server (Java8) that has RESTful services. When a user logs in currently, I send a request from the client to the RESTful Service. This passes a javascript `Person` object to a java `Person` object.

**Question 1**

Does this mean that the password is not exposed. Or is it?

**Question 2**

Once the server receives the `Person` object, it retrieves the `password` String and saves it to a MySQL database.

I would like to encrypt this password, so when someone looks at the database, they cannot read the password. Then when reading from the database, I would need to decrypt it again.

Can anyone please recommend the best and simplest strategy for the above 2 questions.

Thank you

Comment: For secure transport between the client and server use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. For secure transport between the client and server use HTTPS.

Q2. **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.